# Error: "disconnect" is a reserved event name, why am I getting this error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I am building a chat application using react, node.js and socket.io.

I have the following hook that I use for connecting and disconnecting

```
useEffect(() => {
        const { name, room } = queryString.parse(location.search)
        socket = io(ENDPOINT)

        setRoom(room)

        // New user joins room
        socket.emit('join', { name, room }, (userNamesPresent, error) => {
            setUsersPresent(userNamesPresent.userNamesPresent)
        })

        return () => {
            // User leaves room
            socket.emit('disconnect')

            socket.off()
        }
    }, [ENDPOINT, location.search])
```

and I handle it in node like this

```
io.on("connection", socket => {
    socket.on("join", ({ name, room }, callback) => {
        const { error, user } = addUser({id: socket.id, name, room})
    if(error) {
        return callback({error})
    }
    // Emitting a welcome message
    socket.emit('message', {user: 'admin', text: `Welcome to the chat ${user.name}`})

    // Broadcasting to everyone except the connecting user
    socket.broadcast.to(user.room).emit('message', {user: 'admin', text: `${user.name} has joined ${user.room}`})

    socket.join(user.room)

    // Get the users in room 
    const usersPresent = getUsersInRoom(user.room)

    const userNamesPresent = usersPresent.map(user => {
        return {name: user.name}
    })

    callback({userNamesPresent})
})

socket.on('message-sent', (message, callback) => {
    console.log(socket.id)
    const user = getUser(socket.id)

    io.to(user.room).emit('message', {user: user.name, text: message} )

    callback()
})

socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("User has disconnected")

    removeUser(socket.id)
})
})
```

When I leave the page (go back to the previous page for example) I get the following error

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-api/index.html#Event-%E2%80%98disconnect%E2%80%99), instead of doing `socket.emit('disconnect')` in your cleanup function of `useEffect` since `disconnect` is a reserved event name in **Socket.io**, you can use `socket.disconnect()`.

Answer (score 0):

As per socket.io website there is `disconnect` is reserved keyword so you cannnot use it as `socket.emit('disconnect')` instead of it use it as `socket.disconnect()` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, not using react but just nodejs and socket. The error 'disconnect is a reserved event name' shows when reloading the page and or closing the browser. Here is the snippet:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('user disconnected: ', socket.id);

        // remove this player from our players object
        delete players[socket.id];

        // emit a message to all players to remove this player
        io.emit('disconnect', socket.id);

});
```